# Lyx says it's corrupted and cannot find the basic module after upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, lyx

After upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04 Lyx has trouble opening documents I created or creating new documents from templates like `dinbrief` where it says that some files are corrupted, the `basic` module that is required or some other files or dependencies could not be found.

<sub>I reinstalled Ubuntu instead of doing an upgrade and restored a backup of the home directory. I made a list of packages that were installed and only picked the packages and applications I still use. I have been doing this for a few years now for LTS and non-LTS releases and I'm confident that I didn't miss something important, basically installing the lyx meta package and some recommended packages should give me a working setup.</sub>

Since it said the files are corrupted –  – I tried reinstalling the related Lyx and Texlive packages that `apt remove` auto completion offered me but without success. How can I solve this problem? Are my files or the installation corrupted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to open Lyx and from the menu go to *Tools* → *Reconfigure*, then restart Lyx and everything worked like before again.

[image: screenshot of the tools submenu and the reconfigure option]

It doesn't look like Lyx intended to say *"your (Ubuntu) installation is corrupted"* just that I couldn't make sense of the old configuration it found.